# how to store the downloaded copy of the instalation file in the local system in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-windows

I'm trying to store the copy of the installation file in the C: drive this code is working for some application but not all what are the other alternatives. this is for chef for windows server. thank you.

```rb
windows_package '7zip' do
  source 'http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z938-x64.msi'
  remote_file_attributes ({
    :path => 'C:\\7zip.msi',
    :checksum => '7c8e873991c82ad9cfc123415254ea6101e9a645e12977dcd518979e50fdedf3'
 })
end
```

Comment: I don't completely understand. If you want to download the `.msi` file to disk, you can just use `remote_file`. What does "not working" mean? Installing software other than 7zip? Yes, Chef and `windows_package` can't deal with all possible installers out there.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question by copying directly from the Chef docs. The `:path` key there is the path used for the local cache file.

That said, the poise-archive cookbook directly supports 7-Zip and handles installing it for you transparently :)